# How to use mouseMove() function using only x,y co-ordinates using Selenium-Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to move my mouse to a location and tried using `moveMouse()` method. 
There is no proper documentation related to advance interaction API.
Can any one give an example. I have tried the Robot class but its not working for me.

```
public void mouse_move(JSONObject command,WebElement body,Actions builder,JavascriptExecutor js) throws AWTException{

    JSONObject args=command.getJSONObject("args");

    Robot robot= new Robot();

    robot.mouseMove(args.getInt("x"),args.getInt("y")+120);


}
```

Comment: Post the code what you have tried, else you may not find proper answer/suggestion.

Comment: @Sham i have posted the code ..

Comment: do you have xpath for that??

Comment: @SarithaG nope ....only x,y

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 Robot robot= new Robot();
 robot.mouseMove(40,100);
```

Comment: I don't have the offset only x,y location

Comment: May be your not getting x and v values. Once try to fix values of x and y,then try it. Its working for me.

Comment: my values are correct to ..but i cant use robot class

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the position of cursor to a required position, then find the element and use its co-ordinates. If you try to use co-ordinates directly, it might impact when you try to run on a machine which has different resolutions.

```
IWebElement element = Utility.Browser.FindElement(By.Id("elementid"));
Actions act = new Actions(Utility.Browser);
act.MoveByOffset(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y).Build().Perform();

// Utility.Browser is my browser instance.
```

FYI, pseudo-code written in C#.

Comment: dude as u can see from my code i  have only x,y position to work with...if i had the element it would have been easy....diff resolution is not a prob

Comment: It would be great if you post complete details of the problem. Are you automating Web UI or Windows UI? if so is it not possible to get it parent?

Comment: its WebUI ...... i am getting some instructions to move my mouse to x,y location thats it ...moveByOffset() doesnt works as it takes offset not actual mouse location

Answer (score -1):

Moving your mouse to a specific x,y coordinate is not supported by Selenium.

Why is this even tagged as a selenium webdriver question if you're using Robot?